# Determine in Windows if the application is running with elevated privileges

Tags: c++, windows

**This has been solved!** This was accomplished with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Shlobj.h>

int main()
{
    if (!IsUserAnAdmin)
       {
           // Do stuff
       }

    if (IsUserAnAdmin)
       {
           // Do stuff
       }
```

**Thank you to everyone who commented on the post.**

I'm in a bit of a rut with the C++ application I'm developing.

My application requires elevated privileges to function properly, and I'd like to be able to determine if such privileges are present upon runtime. How would I go about doing this? I would like to check immediately after the program is run, and throw an error or proceed with execution (of course)

Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Win32.

Comment: The right way to do this is to add a manifest that says you need administrative privileges and let Windows handle it for you.